# Remove space before bibliography title

Tags: spacing, bibliographies

I have a question very similar to 
[How to remove the huge space in the Bibliography title?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/373441/how-to-remove-the-huge-space-in-the-bibliography-title)
but the solution didn't work for me, probably because I'm using different setting for my documents.

Here is my header and bibliography insert :

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}  
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{times} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{color} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{tocloft} 
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{gensymb}

\begin{document}

Text here.

\clearpage 
\renewcommand{\bibname}{\begin{center} \ul{References} \end{center}} 
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\bfseries \normalsize{References}} 

\bibliographystyle{myunsrt} 
\bibliography{my_biblio.bib}

\end{document}
```

With this code, I have a big space before the Bibliography title, which makes me lose a lot of space in my report, and I would like to get rid of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use the `center` environment, it introduce extra space. Also it is not a good idea to redefine `\bibname` in this way -- the command is also used for the headers.

If you really want an underlined, centered title (which looks imho rather ugly) it would be better to redefine the `thebibliography` environment:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\xpatchcmd\thebibliography{\chapter*{\bibname}}
                          {\chapter*{\centering\ul{References}\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\bfseries \normalsize{References}}}}{}{\fail}
\begin{document}

Text here.
\cite{doody}
\clearpage

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{biblatex-examples.bib}

\end{document}
```

If you want to use a section command you can use this patch instead:

```
\xpatchcmd\thebibliography{\chapter*{\bibname}}
                          {\section*{\centering\ul{References}\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\bfseries \normalsize{References}}}}{}{\fail}
```

Comment: Thanks sir for the advice, but when I apply your code, I still have the space... How can I remove it in accordance with your code ?

Comment: That is the standard layout of chapter. Do you really want something different here?

Comment: Yes sir, I don't use chapters on my reports, only section and subsection. Because I'm really limited in size, I would like to not lose that space in the bibliography page, which will appear weird for readers.

Comment: I'm not a sir, but a woman. And if you don't use chapters then don't use the report class but article.

Comment: I apologize for that Madam.
I truly appreciate all the advices as I'm still learning LaTeX, but I'd like to have something to solve my initial problem... I unfortunately don't have the time to change all the formatting of my report right now.

Comment: Managed to work on something by myself that does the job : `\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\bfseries\Huge}
  {\Large\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}
  {0mm}{\centering}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}
  {0pt}{-10pt}{40pt}`
But I'm not sure it's a clean answer.

Comment: Well if you don't use \chapter in the rest of the document it would be more logical to use \section for the references too. I added the patch for this to the answer.

Comment: Yes indeed, that makes more sense. Thank you for your patience and all the tips.